# Gridview column reordering in Dynamic Data

Tags: gridview, asp.net-dynamic-data

I have a page showing results from database in a gridview in Dynamic data site. By default edit and details links are shown on left side of gridview. I have a peculiar requirement to show these links on right side of gridview. Is there any setting I am missing to acheive this or code modification would also help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thanks to Steve who have provided this code. 
Manoj Please check following link it will be helpful.

http://csharpbits.notaclue.net/2009/05/move-command-link-column-to-end-column.html

Do Best....

Comment: Note that link-only answers are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.